# Updating the text displaid in MACROBUTTON in MS Word

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I am using macrobutton in VBA to have a field whose value is calculated by accessing some other system, and at the same time, I want to be able to double-click on that field to specify some settings used to retrieve data from that other system.

The whole macro stuff works fine but I can not figure out how to change the label on the macrobutton.

Typically the macrobutton looks like this { MACROBUTTON macro_name label {some_arg}{some_arg2} }

I tried accessing selection.fields(1).code.text and even doing regexp to replace 'label' by something else but that just does not work, i.e. either I lose the args or I screw up the label.

Any advice for this issue, or perhaps a suggestion of some other type of field I could use to achieve this? I wouldn't mind using DOCVARIABLE but these can not respond to clicks and carry arguments?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Which MS Office Application are you using? Perhaps a snapshot can help?

Comment: It's MS Word - sorry for that - I edited the question for better clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Sub Testit1()
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strLabel As String
    Dim strNewLabel As String

    strLabel = "Chew"
    strNewLabel = "Devour"

    ' Replace the field code values in the first field to change the label
    strText = ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Code.Text
    ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Code.Text = Replace(strText, strLabel, strNewLabel)
End Sub
```

This will basically do a search and replace inside the field code for the macrobutton field you want to change.  `ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Code.Text` is the part I think you are looking for.

Comment: thx that would work if I didn't have my args, but in my case, I tried just this

`Sub macro_name()

ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Code.Text = ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Code.Text

End Sub`

and when I click the macrobutton, my label turns from 'label' to 'label   some_arg    some_arg2   ' (with chr(19) in between that do not display here). That's what I meant with ' either I lose the args or I screw up the label.'.

Comment: Can you give a specific example so I can see what's going on in Word?

Comment: well let me perhaps be more clear
(1) In a new Word doc, I type 'MACROBUTTON macro_name label some_arg some_arg2'. This displays 'label', highlighted in grey. All fine so far.
(2) I select the whole and press Ctrl-F9 to turn it into a field. I do the same for some_arg and some_arg2 (separately)
(3) I then create a module function macro_name as in my comment 3h ago
(4) when I double-click on my MACROBUTTON, the 'label' is turned into 'label   some_arg some_arg2' (whilst normally it should be unchanged given that my sub marco_name() is pretty much doing nothing).

Makes more sense?

Comment: Ok I do see what is happening when you are inserting fields inside of a field and that's pretty strange.  I don't have a solution to that behavior right away.  Also the { } turns into chr(19) for the open and chr(21) for the close, and you'd think word would accept those when assigning text to recreate the embedded fields but it doesn't.    One possible workaround that may or may not work for you is to not use the embedded fields and instead rebuild the label so that it includes the result text of what the embedded fields show like .Text="MACROBUTTON mymacro Config SamDatabase 1000 Records"

Comment: (the above example assuming {some_arg} evaluates to "SamDatabase" and {some_arg2} evaluates to "1000 Records") and obviously you'd have to run some sort of refresh on document open or a similar event to get these looking right initially.

Comment: @dan-matheus: well that won't work because at the end of the day when I print my document I only want to see the label, not the arguments... Thx anyway!